# Track the ids of beacons which are in region and send the minor id to server in android?

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I Want to Show the Directions in the Tablets when beacons getting connected to that Tablet. Means when beacons in range i need to get the minor ids of that beacons, and send that to a server. How can i please help Me Iam new to Beacons Topic?.I tried this but in this  didExitRegion not called when user gose out please help me hoe detect beacons id when user enter to region?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {

public static final String TAG = "BeaconsEverywhere";

private BeaconManager beaconManager;

int distance;
boolean mInsideZone = false;
Identifier minorID;

double distanceLong;
ListView beaconListView;
private Handler mHandler;

private int i;

ArrayAdapter beaconAdapter;

public TextView distanceText;

public TextView distanceName1;

public ImageView distanceImage;

public String name1;

public boolean exitRegion = false;

public String minorString;

List<String> beaconList;
List<String> con;
Set<String> mBeaconsProcessed;
String s1,s2,s3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    name1 = intent.getStringExtra("beacon1");



    distanceText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distanceText);

    distanceText.setText("No beacons found yet, please wait");

    distanceName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name1);

    distanceName1.getText();

    distanceName1.setText("How far away is "+name1+"?");

    distanceText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distanceText);

    distanceText.getText();

    distanceText.setText("Distance: " + distance+ "metres");

    distanceImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.distanceImage);
    //alertDialogue();

    i = 0;
   con = new ArrayList<String>();

    beaconAdapter = new 
 ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
 beaconListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.beaconListView);
beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()

            .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

    beaconManager.bind(this);





}




@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {


    final Region region = new Region("myBeaons",null, null, null);
    beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {

        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {

            try {

                Log.d(TAG, "didEnterRegion");

                //  String st=region.getId1().toString();
                con.clear();


                beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);


            } catch (RemoteException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        @Override

        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {

            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "didExitRegion");
                con.clear();
                beaconList.clear();
                beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
            }
            catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
            int j=0;
            j=i;
            String s=Integer.toString(j);
        }
    });
    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override

        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(final Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override

                public void run() {


     //stuff that updates ui

                    beaconList = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for(Beacon oneBeacon : beacons) {

                        distanceLong = oneBeacon.getDistance();


                        if (oneBeacon.getDistance() < 1.0 && mInsideZone == 
                      false) {


                            minorID = oneBeacon.getId3();

                            minorString = minorID.toString();
                            final String distanceString = 
                        String.valueOf(minorID);
                            beaconList.add(distanceString);
                            mInsideZone = true;

                        }
                        if (oneBeacon.getDistance() > 5.0&&mInsideZone == 
   true)
                        {
                            mInsideZone = false;
                            con=new ArrayList<String>();
                        }
                    }


                }});

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

  //stuff that updates ui
                    if (con.size()>0)
                    {
                        if (con.containsAll(beaconList) )
                        {

                        }
                        else {
                            con.clear();
                            con=beaconList;
                            calls(beaconList);

                        }

                    }
                    else {

                        if (beaconList.size()>0) {
                            con = beaconList;
                            calls(beaconList);
                        }
                    }





                }});

        }
    });




    try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
public void calls(List<String> names)
{
List<beconsclass> bss=new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0;i<names.size();i++)
{
beconsclass bs=new beconsclass();
if(names.get(i).equals("32109"))
{
    bs.setName("JON");
}
if(names.get(i).equals("25335"))
{
    bs.setName("MIKEY");
}


bss.add(bs);
}
if (bss.size()>0)
{
Adapter aa=new Adapter(MainActivity.this,bss);
beaconListView.setAdapter(aa);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please add what you have already done. That is helpful while answering the question.

Comment: yes! i updated my code please help me

Comment: Dou you get a call to didEnterRegion when the beacon appears?

Comment: yes! can we find any id when called didEnterRegion to send details of becons to server in android

Comment: any other way to get id of beacons

Comment: What exactly do you do to try and get a region exit?  How long do you wait?

Comment: okay! i got it. and why its not visible when i close(pressing back button) and reopen the app